# DynamicFrame resolve choice between Array and Struct

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm using AWS Glue to crawl XML files and add them to a Glue database table. The `DynamicFrame` I'm using identifies several choices in the XML schema. I can resolve most of them, but there's one case that I can't figure out.

The relevant part of the XML structure is:

```
<root>
  <order>
     <lineitems>
       <lineitem>
          ...
       </lineitem>
     </lineitems>
  </order>
</root>
```

The `DynamicFrame` shows `lineitems` as a `struct` and `lineitems/lineitem` as a `choice` between `array` or `struct`, I suspect because some orders have one `lineitem`, whereas other orders have multiple `lineitems`. I've tried calling `resolveChoice` with `project:array`, but that results in `element:unknown` so I can no longer see the structure of the `lineitem`. I'm not sure what else to try here, any ideas?